# multiple destination for statsd in object-server.conf of swift open stack

Tags: configuration, monitoring, object-storage, openstack-swift, statsd

I want to send my statsd metrics from object server module of swift open stack to multiple hosts.
How should I change my `object-server.conf` in `/etc/swift` path?

The present version of `object-server.conf1` is:

```
log_statsd_host = localhost
log_statsd_port = 8125
log_statsd_default_sample_rate = 1.0
log_statsd_sample_rate_factor = 1.0
log_statsd_metric_prefix = swift
```

I tried to use multiple hosts in this form:

```
log_statsd_host = localhost,monitoring-server
```

but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the swift documentation and found out that you can just send statsd metrics to one server.

So it is impossible to send swift statsd metrics to more than one statsd server.